# Как правильно задать border кнопке (CSS)?

Tags: css

1. Как правильно задать `border` кнопке в виде градиента, мой вариант нормальный, или есть лучше?
2. Как дополнительно задать кнопке `border-radius` (сейчас он не применяется)?

```css
button
{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff7382, #cb2fe7);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>Кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нормально, для `border-radius` надо немного подправить код:

```css
button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white) padding-box, linear-gradient(to right, #ff7382, #cb2fe7) border-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>Кнопка</button>
```

button с **transparent** и оберткой:

```css
div {
  background: red; /*Цвет для отображения transparent в button*/
  border-radius: 20px; 
  border-left: 10px solid #ff7382;
  border-right: 10px solid #cb2fe7;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff7382, #cb2fe7), linear-gradient(to right, #ff7382, #cb2fe7);
  background-size: 100% 10px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  width: 200px;  
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Кнопка</button>
</div>
```

Comment: А в данном случае полностью прозрачный центр кнопки можно как-то сделать?

Comment: К сожалению, нет.

Comment: Но можно если обернуть кнопку. Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Да, про обертку тоже думал, но проблема в том, что теперь будем видеть фон обертки...

Comment: Фон обвертке можно задать прозрачный background: transparent, в примере просто красный задал, для наглядности.

Answer (score 4):

1. Нормально.
2. `border-image` и `border-radius` не дружат.

Можно обойти это, сделав так:

```css
button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff7382, #cb2fe7);
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px #fff inset;
  background-origin: border-box;
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Можно без проблем удалить `background: transparent` и `border-image-slice: 1` и ничего не поменяется.

Comment: каюсь. скопировал из веб-инспектора все стили вместо только нужных...

Comment: Всё нормально, я удалил.